Specify compiler for installing ports
I'm on Windows, and by default it finds Visual Studio's cl.exe. I'd like it to use clang instead.
I'd prefer to specify it per project (which uses a manifest file).
So far, I've seen posts that complain why it can't be simply set with
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang-cl.exe" )

There's also a flag DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE, which seems irrelevant since it seems similar to setting the environment before calling cmake.
